# What is meant by 'Sort pub dependencies'?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I am trying to migrate a project into null safety mode,after migrating and clearing all the errors, I am getting this problem named '**Sort pub dependencies.dart(sort_pub_dependencies)**'. I searched Google but couldn't find any solution. Any help would really be appreciated :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`sort_pub_dependencies` is a lint that comes from the Dart linter: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/sort_pub_dependencies.html

The lint is activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file in your project.

```yaml
linter:
 rules:
  - sort_pub_dependencies
```

Basically, it is telling you to sort the name of the dependencies alphabetically in the `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  markdown:
  archive:  # put archive before markdown
```

You can remove the line from `analysis_options.yaml` if you don't want to enforce this rule.

Comment: Sort dependencies by name?

Comment: @SyedAliRazaBokhari Yes

Comment: Removing linter is not a solution right?

Answer (score 4):

It isn't a necessary rule, you can just turn that off by going to your analysis_options.yaml file and adding this line under rules:

```
sort_pub_dependencies: false
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also a package for sorting the dependecies with more features
on pub.dev.

You add the package to your `dev_dependencies` section in pubspec.yaml file or use `flutter pub add --dev pubspec_dependency_sorter`.

Then run
`flutter pub run pubspec_dependency_sorter`
The packages will be automatically sorted for you.

https://pub.dev/packages/pubspec_dependency_sorter

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: I have edited the answer and its clearer now

Comment: This package indiscriminately removes all comments from pubspec.yaml. I don't recommend this tool unless you don't need to have any comments in your pubspec.yaml file